# How to draw to offscreen color buffer in OpenGL and then draw the result to a sprite surface?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is a description of the problem:

1. I want to render some VBO shapes (rectangles, circles, etc) to an off screen framebuffer object. This could be any arbitrary shape.
2. Then I want to draw the result on a simple sprite surface as a texture, but not on the entire screen itself.

I can't seem to get this to work correctly.

When I run the code, I see the shapes being drawn all over the screen, but not in the sprite in the middle. It remains blank. Even though it seems like I set up the FBO with 1 color texture, it still only renders to screen even if I select the FBO object into context.

What I want to achieve is these shapes being drawn to an off screen texture (using an FBO, obviously) and then render it on the surface of a sprite (or a cube, or we) drawn somewhere on the screen. Yet, whatever I draw, appears to be drawn in the screen itself.

The tex(tex_object_ID); function is just a short-hand wrapper for OpenGL's standard texture bind. It selects a texture into current rendering context.

No matter what I try I get this result: The sprite is blank, but all these shapes should appear there, not on the main screen. (Didn't I bind rendering to FBO? Why is it still rendering on screen?)

[image]

I think it is just a logistics of setting up FBO in the right order that I am missing. Can anyone tell what's wrong with my code?

Not sure why the background is red, as I clear it after I select the FBO. It is the sprite that should get the red background & shapes drawn on it.

```
/*-- Initialization -- */

GLuint texture = 0;
GLuint Framebuffer = 0;

GLuint GenerateFrameBuffer(int dimension)
{
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, dimension, dimension, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &Framebuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, Framebuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);

    glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR);
    glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        console_log("GL_FRAMEBUFFER != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE\n");

    return texture;
}

// Store framebuffer texture (should I store texture here or Framebuffer object?)
GLuint FramebufferHandle = GenerateFrameBuffer( 256 );
```

Standard OpenGL initialization code follows, memory is allocated, VBO's are created and bound, etc. This works correctly and there aren't errors in initialization. I can render VBOs, polygons, textured polygons, lines, etc, on standard double buffer with success.

Next, in my render loop I do the following:

```
// Possible problem?
// Should FramebufferHandle be passed here?
// I tried "texture" and "Framebuffer " as well, to no effect:

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, FramebufferHandle); 

// Correct projection, just calculates the view based on current zoom
Projection = setOrthoFrustum(-config.zoomed_width/2, config.zoomed_width/2, -config.zoomed_height/2, config.zoomed_height/2, 0, 100);
View.identity();
Model.identity();

// Mini shader, 100%  *guaranteed* to work, there are no errors in it (works normally on the screen)
shaderProgramMini.use();

//Clear frame buffer with blue color
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);// | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Set yellow to draw different shapes on the framebuffer
color = {1.0f,1.0f,0.0f};

// Draw several shapes (already correctly stored in VBO objects)
Memory.select(VBO_RECTANGLES); // updates uniforms
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, Memory.renderable[VBO_RECTANGLES].indexIndex);
Memory.select(VBO_CIRCLES); // updates uniforms
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, Memory.renderable[VBO_CIRCLES].indexIndex);
Memory.select(VBO_2D_LIGHT); // updates uniforms
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, Memory.renderable[VBO_2D_LIGHT].indexIndex);

// Done writing to framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

// Correct projection, just calculates the view based on current zoom
Projection = setOrthoFrustum(-config.zoomed_width/2, config.zoomed_width/2, -config.zoomed_height/2, config.zoomed_height/2, 0, 100);
View.identity();
Model.identity();
Model.scale(10.0);

// Select texture shader to draw what was drawn on offscreen Framebuffer / texture
// Standard texture shader, 100% *guaranteed* to work, there are no errors in it (works normally on the screen)
shaderProgramTexture.use();

// This is a wrapper for bind texture to ID, just shorthand function name
tex(texture); // FramebufferHandle; // ? // maybe the mistake in binding to the wrong target object?

color = {0.5f,0.2f,0.0f};
Memory.select(VBO_SPRITE); Select a square VBO for rendering sprites (works if any other texture is assigned to it)

// finally draw the sprite with Framebuffer's texture:
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, Memory.renderable[VBO_SPRITE].indexIndex);
```

I may have gotten the order of something completely wrong. Or FramebufferHandle/Framebuffer/texture object is not passed to something correctly. But I spent all day, and hope someone more experienced than me can see the mistake.

Answer (score 4):

`GL_COLOR` is not an accepted value for [`glDrawBuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffer.xhtml)

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Compatibility Profile Specification, 17.4.1 Selecting Buffers for Writing, Table 17.4 and Table 17.5, page 628](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.compatibility.pdf)

> `NONE`, `FRONT_LEFT`, `FRONT_RIGHT`, `BACK_LEFT`, `BACK_RIGHT`, `FRONT`, `BACK`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FRONT_AND_BACK`, `AUXi`.
>
> Arguments to `DrawBuffer` when the context is bound to a default framebuffer, and the buffers they indicate. The same arguments are valid for `ReadBuffer`, but only a single buffer is selected as discussed in section.

> `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi`
>
> Arguments to DrawBuffer(s) and ReadBuffer when the context is bound to a framebuffer object, and the buffers they indicate. *i* in `COLOR_ATTACHMENTi` may range from zero to the value of `MAX_COLOR_ATTACHMENTS` minus one.

Thsi means that [`glDrawBuffer(GL_COLOR);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawBuffer.xhtml) and [`glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR);`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glReadBuffer.xhtml) will generate a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.
Try to use `COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` instead.

Furthermore, [`glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCheckFramebufferStatus.xhtml), checkes the completeness of the framebuffer object  which is bound to the *target*.

This means that

```
glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE
```

has to be done **before**

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Or you have to use:

```
glNamedFramebufferReadBuffer(Framebuffer, GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```